# Restored Keychain doesn't persist

Tags: time-machine, restore, keychain, migration

I've just migrated MBPro to Mojave. Everything came through nicely, except the keychain. After upgrade, the keychain has been wiped fresh by Migration Assistant.

So, I moved contents of `~/Library/Keychains` into a new dir called `~Library/Keychains/OLD` and restored the following from Timemachine: **login.keychain** and **metadata.keychain** (There were no other files in backup of `~/Library/Keychains` because there was no AppleID registered on the computer at the time of the backup).

After restoring, I Launch Keychain Access and my recovered items are all there and recognized. I see that Keychain Access has added some files to the `~/Library/Keychains` directory, presumably for the iCloud keychain, which I have turned off (resulting in Local Items, only).

When I restart, it's like Groundhog day (I've done this several times). The restored items are gone and the Login keychain items are just a handful of default items, generated by Keychain on launch. My System Keychain still has my wifi PW and a bunch of old SSID's from past travels, so the problem is just with Login Keychain and Local Items ie: only those associated with this username.

I have de-selected Keychain Access in iCloud, so that it wouldn't try to sync an empty file to my MB. So, I'm at a total loss. Thoughts?

Comment: Try importing the items from your old keychain.  In Keychain Access File -> Import Items point it to the old keychain.  Fairly certain it's the login.keychain you need.  Perhaps the old keychain file is partially damaged, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this James. For the benefit of other readers:  I did try to Import from old keychain, but that wasn't working for some reason I don't recall (was a month ago). It only confirmed for me that Keychain is generally problematic. As this is my wife's computer, I had her migrate (manually) to a different PW manager. I've been happy with Roboform on all my devices, so that's what she's using too. Keychain has proven to be too enmeshed in the OS and is just messy and annoying to me.

Comment: Did you upgrade to Mojave from a very old macOS version? It’s possible to leap frog over several OS versions and perhaps the Keychain file format was so old it wasn’t able to be used. Incremental OS upgrades would have converted the Keychain file format potentially. Regardless, the Keychain file is an encrypted storage and if damaged it will make recovery impossible unless you have multiple versioned backups. You don’t have to use the Keychain except for the initial macOS login. 3rd party solutions can sync outside the Apple ecosystem. But you still need to backup the saved passwords.